# How to handle interacting decorators

Tags: oop, design-patterns, decorator

Given the classic coffee decorator example (copied from Wikipedia).

```
public interface Coffee {
    public double getCost();
}

public class SimpleCoffee implements Coffee {
    public double getCost() {
        return 1;
    }
}

public abstract class CoffeeDecorator implements Coffee {
    protected final Coffee decoratedCoffee;
    public CoffeeDecorator(Coffee c) {
        this.decoratedCoffee = c;
    }
    public double getCost() {
        return decoratedCoffee.getCost();
    }
}

class WithMilk extends CoffeeDecorator {
    public WithMilk(Coffee c) {
        super(c);
    }
    public double getCost() {
        return super.getCost() + MILKCOST;
    }
    public int someAttribute;
}

class WithMocha extends CoffeeDecorator {
    public WithMocha(Coffee c) {
        super(c);
    }
    public double getCost() {
        return super.getCost() + MOCHACOST;
    }
}
```

Suppose I want my WithMocha cost to use someAttribute if the WithMilk decorator exists, how would one design such a decorator system?

Is the decorator pattern even the best approach?

Answer (score 2):

No it isn't, as casting the coffee instance to a decorator would violate [Liskovs substution principle](http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/05/27/liskovs-substitution-principle/).

As your question do not detail the real problem that you want to solve it's hard to give a proper answer.

If you want to construct objects where the different parts can interact the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) is a much better alternative.

Comment: The builder pattern seems interesting, I'll take a look at it, thanks!

Comment: Casting does not violate Liskov Substitution. The two concepts are largely orthogonal. Casting involves syntactic substitution, while Liskov's principle involves semantic substitution.

Comment: @jaco0646: Depends on if you throw an exception that the base class do not throw (like `NotSupportedException`)

Comment: A subclass method either violates Liskov Substitution or it does not. Casting the subclass's reference type cannot change that fact.